# Connecting constants in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On a surface of revolution a line ( primes are with respect to this line) is drawn at a point P making angles $(\phi$ , $\psi) $ respect to symmetry axis and meridian such that for constants $c_i$

$$ \frac{\cos \phi\cdot \phi^{'} }{r \cos \psi} = c_1 ;\, 
  \frac{\cos \phi\cdot \cos\psi }{r ^2}=c_2; $$

Show that

$$ \frac{ \cos \phi}{r } = c_3 ; \,\frac {\cos \phi }{\cos \psi}={c_4}; $$

and express  new constants $(c_3,c_4)$  in terms of given constants $(c_1,c_2).$

Background is that I have numerically integrated them with arbitrary constants. The equations represent spirals on a sphere seen in the numerical solution.

I am trying to connect the constants.

Thanks in advance for an analytical or any other recourse. If so desired shall upload images of integrated solution surfaces. The second part of building relation among constants is what stumps me out at the moment.

Regards

Comment: You mean like $c_2c_4=c_3^2$? You can not get rid of $c_1$, as there is no other equation containing $ϕ'$.

Comment: That is when algebraically seen. For instance using quotient rule  we have $ c_4=\dfrac{ \sin \phi \cdot \phi^{'}} {  \sin \psi \cdot \ \psi^{'} }.$